# Method to paste whisker template

Tags: r, loops

I am writing a program to generate whisker template in a loop, and I want to paste them together. For every template, my code looks like this:

```
script[i] <- whisker.render(template_pdf[i], data = parameter)
```

Is there a method to paste all the **script[i]** together? I know I can paste all the chunks first and then use function `whisker.render` just for one time, but that will cause some trouble in my particular case. If I can paste all the **script[i]** together, that will be convenient for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `script` is a character vector you can do

```
paste(script, collapse = "\n")
```

with `\n` (newline) the character inserted between the script elements.

When `script` is a list, you can do

```
do.call(paste, c(script, sep ="\n"))
```